# How to save text that has been entered into a plain text field in android

Tags: android, text, field

I want to be able to save text that is entered into a plain text field.

I have got a save button there which is all defined. So I want to be able to click that save button and the string within that text field will be saved to my text field. I am going to put a load button there too to load the text saved.
I have a little idea on how to do this but not much at all. If anyone could help me that would be great.
Thanks

Comment: You want to save while your application is running or you want it even after when the application has stopped?

Comment: if any of the answer worked for you accept that. and do some research before asking.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you should do.

1. You can create a database table, when save button is pressed, text from edittext field is saved in databse table.
2. When load button is pressed, a cursor should search id database table and get text previously entered, then by using set text function for edittext field, you can load that text to the edittext field.

Hope it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

what actually you want to do?
 after onClick of save text should be saved from text field to text field means what?
load button for loading the saved text but from where it is going to fetch that save text?

please be clear and paste your code what you have done to achieve this.